How to send binary data containing 0x0D without triggering a carriage return using AT commands
I am using AT Commands to interface with a satellite modem. I need to send bytes of data through this serial connection. My problem is that the AT command is terminated when it finds a carriage return, or the hex code 0x0D. Given that my data is not plain text, but rather plain binary data, how can I ensure that the command will not be ended if this binary data happens to have the hex code 0x0D somewhere in it?
I am using an Iridium Edge device and the AT-SBDWT command.

You should transmit ESC before the 0x0d, and also of course before ESC occurring in the data.

Maybe you should use this command? Iridium ISU AT Command Reference page 104 5.168 +SBDWB - Short Burst Data: Write Binary Data to the ISU And it's maybe the same here. +SBDWB

@kunif - That is exactly what I’m looking for and in my scenario solves the problem completely. Thank you very much.
